# running a script after jquery loaded element

Tags: jquery, load

I have a several html files that has `<a href="">` tags that goes elsewhere, but because I added a music player on top I started using jquery load and because I'm lazy I added this script to jquery load all the links. (This script is on the index file and the other files have only the elements needed ie. no `<body>` etc.)

```
$("a").live('click', function(){
$("#main").load($(this).attr("href"));
return false;
});
```

however it works only on the first page and after contents change with jquery load it doesn't work. If I understood correctly because load happened after the script ran but .live should handle this right? I'm a beginner so there might be something I misunderstood.

Or are there any other ways to know if jquery load happened and run the script again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `live` is deprecated, you should use `on` in a delegation manner instead. And you need to bind it on a parent element, where you want to place the loaded content in. The problem is, that when you load another content your event is not getting triggered correctly anymore ...

Another hint: use the `preventDefault` function to stop gefault bahvior of the `a` tags.

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#main").load($(this).attr("href"));
    return false;
});
```